# Is it possible to use different credentials for basic(?) authentication in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome and I have a site that uses the Tomcat Java webserver. When I go to log into the manager application it uses the basic authentication (Chrome pops up the username/password dialog). Occasionally I use the wrong username/password for the system, and I'm not able to change the credentials.

I've tried deleting the cookies for the domain through the developer console, but that didn't work.

I can start an incognito window and then log in using the correct credentials just fine. Is there some easy way (aside from opening an incognito window) to let me log out & back in again?

Comment: If its Java then you have to clear your Java cache, which Chrome wouldn't clean out, since it didn't actually create it.

Comment: The site only uses Java on the back end, @Ramhound

Comment: Shouldn't Tomcat use JSESSIONID cookie?

Comment: It does, but deleting the cookie doesn't help. I think it's Chrome hanging on to the credential for some reason